# Why does elevetaion not work in EditText?

Tags: android

EditText elevation works in xml, but doesn't work on the device. It looks normal in Android studio. The shadow is missing when the app is launched in a device.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_search_product"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_edit_text_search"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_loop"
        android:hint="Product"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guide_line_end"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guide_line_start"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_view_search_screen_title" />
```

Comment: Show the output screen as well

Answer (score 0):

Elevation attribute only works on API 21 and higher. Is your API lower than 21? And can you please try to add a background color to your background_edit_text_search layout just in case if it doesn't have a solid color.

Comment: My API is 24. background_edit_text_search has white background color :(

Answer (score 0):

try to use `AppcompatEdittext` instead. and make sure that you set a backgorund which is not **transparent**.

```
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
```

Answer (score 0):

I set this in Manifest file and it works for me.

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```